# How to bind more parameters in javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    fs.readFile( files[i], function( file, error, data ) {
       console.log("Successfully read a file", file)
    }.bind(null, files[i]));
}
```

I want to use `Node.js` to read all files under a certain dir.
In the callback loop, files[i] does not exist due to javascript closure.
So I bind it but it appears as the first parameter.
I wonder how to make it as the last parameter, thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an IIFE to close in the variable?

Comment: `I wonder how to make it as the last parameter, thanks` - simple, you cant

Comment: And why wouldn't `files[i]` be defined in that code?

Comment: I know I should use closure, but just curious if there is a more elegant way to add more parameters for Function

Comment: @adeneo why wouldn't you use `files.forEach` and have perfectly readable code

Comment: @JaromandaX - true

Comment: `add more parameters` vs `make it as the last parameter` - which is it? you can add more  parameters, easy, bind can not bind parameters anywhere but the beginning - if you know how .bind works, you'd know why - see polyfill in the documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill)

Comment: @ adeneo   because it's in async callback(fs.readFile), the i will be file.length before the callback triggers

Comment: @jiajianrong - i got that, but why would you want to access `files[i]` inside the callback, shouldn't the data from the file be enough? Anyway, as noted by Jaromanda X `files.forEach( (file) => { .. })` would let you access the filename anywhere

Comment: @adeneo - however, the answer to the **question** is nothing to do with forEach - the answer is *you can't do what you want to do* :p

Comment: @Jaromanda X your suggest is perfect for my case. So now just wondering if we can define a special function (such as Function.prototype.addMorePara) to use  function( error, data, p1, p2... ) ? Thanks.

Comment: `if we can define a special function` - we? no. you? nothing stopping you from having a go at it

Comment: Like below usage:  
   fs.readFile( files[i], function( error, data, p1 ) {
       console.log("Successfully read a file", p1)
    }.addMoreParam('hello');

Comment: @Jaromanda X  Thanks anyway. I tried a while and failed to achieve such a   Function.prototype.addMoreParam.   So you really save my time on unachieveable work

Comment: You could bind the 'this', just do bind(files[i])  this will then equal the file and you can keep your error / data params without, and access file using 'this'.

Comment: just remove the useless `bind` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, as it's something a lot of javascript programmers make a mistake with. @torazaburo even said why not remove the pointless bind, well it's not pointless because fs.readFile is asynchronous.

I've created a little snippet below to show different ideas, there might be more.

1st is do nothing and don't bind, and is the only option that @torazaburo mentions that fails.

2nd test, is like the OP's where he has binded to the first parameter.

3rd test is binding the 'this', may as well as it's only going to be window object otherwise.. :)

4th test, use a function closure.

5th test, use the 'let', as this will capture the local scope not just the functional scope.  This of course requires es6, babel etc.

6th test, use a sort of proxy function to alter the order of the parameters, this is the closesest option I can think for the OP..

```js
var files = ['file1','file2','file3'];

function readFile(fn, callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback(null, 'filedata for ' + fn);
  },1);
}

//test 1 do nothing
function test1() {
  console.log('test1, dont use bind');
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    readFile( files[i], function( file, error, data ) {
       console.log("Successfully read a file " + files[i])
    });
  }
}

//test 2 bind the first parameter
function test2() {
  console.log('test2, bind the first paramenter');
  for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    readFile( files[i], function( file, error, data ) {
      console.log("Successfully read a file " + file)
    }.bind(null, files[i]));
  }
}

//bind 'this', it only going to be the window object anyway, so why not use it
function test3() {
  console.log('test3, bind the this');
  for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    readFile( files[i], function( error, data ) {
      console.log("Successfully read a file " + this)
    }.bind(files[i]));
  }  
}

//use a function closure, luckly forEach is going to do that for us
function test4() {
  console.log('test4, use a closure');
  files.forEach(function (file) {
    readFile(file, function( error, data ) {
      console.log("Successfully read a file " + file)
    });
  });
}

//use let
function test5() {
  console.log('test5, use let instead of var');
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    readFile( files[i], function( error, data ) {
       console.log("Successfully read a file " + files[i])
    });
  }
}

//create proxy function
function proxy_readFile(fn, cb) {
  return readFile(fn, function (error, data) { 
    cb(error, data, fn) });
}

function test6() {
  console.log('test6, use a proxy function');
  for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    proxy_readFile( files[i], function(error, data, file) {
      console.log("Successfully read a file " + file)
    }); 
  }
}



setTimeout(test1,100);
setTimeout(test2,200);
setTimeout(test3,300);
setTimeout(test4,400);
setTimeout(test5,500); 
setTimeout(test6,600);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a wrapper iife as a closure:

```js
for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    fs.readFile( files[i], (function(file) {
      return function(err, data){
        onFileRead(file, error, data);
      }
    })(files[i]));
}
function onFileRead(file, error, data){
  console.log("Successfully read a file", file)
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need for closure here. `files[i]` is just an argument passed to the `fs.readFile` function which gets invoked synchronously once in each turn of the `for` loop.

Comment: @Redu: it's used in the callback. GudzDaniel: You're using a solution that was used before we had `let` variables.